# a recursive function to calculate height of n-airy tree

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

I need your help in solving these issue. I was solving in visual studio a recursive function to calculate the height of n-ary tree. When I tested it in a small tree, it gave me the height's value. However, when I compiled the code of a bigger data, the running took more than 3 days with no results. The function i used is as follow:

```
unsigned int Height(NaryNode *root)
{
   unsigned int HeightMax = 0;
   unsigned i;
   for (i = 0; i < root->nchild; i++)
   {
      if (Height(root->child[i])>HeightMax)
        HeightMax = Height(root->child[i]);
   }
   return (HeightMax + 1);
}
```

Thank you in advance..

Comment: your recursive call has no base case like - `if(root==NULL) return 0;`

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS There is no need, the function traverses down and starts at the root.

Comment: @riodoro1 I do not understand.

Comment: @riodoro1 What it will return when `root` is `NULL` ?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. And please ask one question at a time, especially if the questions are totally unrelated.

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS It will gracefully crash on the third line of the function after it tries to dereference a null pointer. But that's ok because You use the function by calling it with the root and only go down from it, You never go up the tree.

Comment: @riodoro1 So you agree that it should have a base case ?

Comment: @GAURANG VYAS: There is a base case; if a node has no children, then ... `for (i = 0; i < root->nchild; i++)` is not entered; the function will (at least not recursively) be called with a `NULL`-value for `root`; `HeightMax` remains `0`,  and the function returns `(HeightMax+1)` then, right?

Comment: @StephanLechner Okay  I did not notice that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're computing the height twice for each subtree.
If the tree is deep this is going to take a long time.

For simplicity, assume that each node has only one child.

Then starting at the root, you compute the height of its child twice.
For each of these computations, you compute the height of that child's child twice – that's four function calls.
For each of these four, you're making two computations – that's eight.

For each level down, you're doubling the number of calls to `Height`, and computing the height of a tree with 32 single-child nodes needs more than four *billion* function calls.

Store the result of `Height(root->child[i])` in  a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are calling the same recursive function with the same parameter twice, this will make things quite slow.

```
unsigned int Height(NaryNode *root)
{
   unsigned int HeightMax = 0;
   unsigned i;
   for (i = 0; i < root->nchild; i++)
   {
      auto currHeigth = Height(root->child[i])
      if (currHeight > HeightMax)
        HeightMax = currHeight;
   }
   return (HeightMax + 1);
}
```

will give you a huge speedup.

Comment: You are right, I will try it. Thank you for your help.